# vba to get email senders details from GAL

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to get the email senders's details (eg. name, job title, dept etc) from a folder. I am able to get required details for the conacts in my address book, however I am not getting details about the contacts in GAL.

My code is as below:

```
Public Sub DisplaySenderDetails()
Dim Sender As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim rCount As Long
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Dim enviro As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strColB, strColC, strColD, strColE, strColF, strColG As String
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim obj As Object
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strdate As String 
Dim oExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Dim olGAL As Outlook.AddressList
Dim olEntry As Outlook.AddressEntries



 ' Get Excel set up
   enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
       'the path of the workbook
    strPath = enviro & "\Documents\test2.xlsx"
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
      Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
      Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")



  Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set olGAL = objNS.GetGlobalAddressList()
  Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Abc")
  Set objItems = objFolder.Items
  Set olEntry = olGAL.AddressEntries

  For Each obj In objItems

  With obj

    Set Sender = obj.Sender
    Set olItem = obj

  If TypeName(obj) = "MailItem" Then

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To olEntry.Count

    If olEntry.Item.Address = Sender.Address Then


        Set oExUser = Sender.GetExchangeUser
        rCount = xlSheet.Range("B" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row
        rCount = rCount + 1

        strdate = DateValue(olItem.ReceivedTime)
        If strdate >= #7/1/2016# Then
            strColB = Sender.Name
            strColC = oExUser.JobTitle
            strColD = oExUser.Department
            strColE = oExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
            strColF = olItem.Subject
            strColG = olItem.ReceivedTime


            xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = strColB
            xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = strColC
            xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = strColD
            xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = strColE
            xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount) = strColF
            xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount) = strColG

            strColB = ""
            strColC = ""
            strColD = ""
            strColE = ""
            strColF = ""
            trColG = ""
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
    Next i
End If

End With
Next

Set obj = Nothing
Set objItems = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Comment out the line On Error GoTo ErrHandler. What is the error if any. Provide results of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following function

```
Private Function getSmtpMailAddress(sMail As Outlook.mailItem) As String
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim strEntryId As String
    Dim objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objSession As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objAddressentry As Outlook.AddressEntry
    Dim objExchangeUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim objReply As Outlook.mailItem

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If sMail.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then
        strAddress = sMail.SenderEmailAddress
    Else
        Set objReply = sMail.reply()
        Set objRecipient = objReply.recipients.item(1)

        strEntryId = objRecipient.EntryID

        objReply.Close OlInspectorClose.olDiscard

        Set objSession = getMapiSession

        strEntryId = objRecipient.EntryID

        Set objAddressentry = objSession.GetAddressEntryFromID(strEntryId)
        Set objExchangeUser = objAddressentry.GetExchangeUser()

        strAddress = objExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress()
    End If

    getSmtpMailAddress = strAddress

    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    getSmtpMailAddress = "???"
End Function
```

Helper routines in a separate module:

```
Private objNameSpace As NameSpace

Private Sub logonMapiSession()
    Set objNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    objNameSpace.Logon Profile:="", Password:="", ShowDialog:=False, NewSession:=False
End Sub

Public Sub logoffMapiSession()
    If Not (objNameSpace Is Nothing) Then
        objNameSpace.Logoff

        Set objNameSpace = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Public Function getMapiSession() As NameSpace
    If objNameSpace Is Nothing Then
        logonMapiSession
    End If

    Set getMapiSession = objNameSpace
End Function
```

Comment: Hello Axel. Thank you for your response. I am actually a newbie in vba. I have no issues getting email address. I am unable to get email sender's (who are not present in my address book) job title and department from GAL. What would be the solution?

Comment: You could evaluate other properties of Outlook.ExchangeUser as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866281.aspx)

Comment: I tried the code provided there. It is saving all the GAL contacts in excel book. Whereas I am trying to fetch only selected email sender's details from GAL.

Comment: You have to modify my function. Rather than `strAddress = objExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress()`, you could query the properties which are of interest to you.